# VB.net Query on Datagrid view

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to display value in datagrid not the id. 
I have two Tables
Table1, having empid, receivedbyid, releasebyid, this ID's refer ONLY on Table2
whereby Table2 having id, name.

I required to display on datagrid Table1 respected NAME not ID.
ex Table1 ID's are 1,3,3
   Table2 data is, 1 - Name1, 2 - Name2, 3-Name3

Output should be,

```
  Name1, Name3, Name3
```

Comment: please write your question in brief with table structure and table data.

Comment: Hi Chetan. Table1 i have fields, empid, receivedbyid,releasebyid, having data as 1,3,3 respectively. Table2, I have fields ID,Name. I have data in table2 as ID (1), Name (jay) , ID (2), Name (jay1) , ID(3)  Name(jay3) , I want to display on datagrid table 1 on which instead of ID it will get value from table2. Hope this is somehow clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C#

```
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.appendLine(" select b.name as EmpName,c.Name as Receivedby,d.name as releasedby from table1 as a ");
         sb.appendLine(" inner join table2 as b on a.empid = b.id ");
         sb.appendLine(" inner join table2 as c on a.receivedbyid = b.id ");
         sb.appendLine(" inner join table2 as d on a.releasebyid = b.id ");

         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConString);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.tostring(), conn);
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(dataTable);


                GridVIew.DataSource = dataTable;
                GridVIew.DataBind();
```

For vb

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
sb.appendLine(" select b.name as EmpName,c.Name as Receivedby,d.name as releasedby from table1 as a ")
sb.appendLine(" inner join table2 as b on a.empid = b.id ")
sb.appendLine(" inner join table2 as c on a.receivedbyid = b.id ")
sb.appendLine(" inner join table2 as d on a.releasebyid = b.id ")

Dim conn As New SqlConnection(MyConString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sb.tostring(), conn)
conn.Open()
Dim dataTable As New DataTable()
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

da.Fill(dataTable)


GridVIew.DataSource = dataTable
GridVIew.DataBind()
```

Comment: Hi Chetan, your response is highly appreciated. The code give me an idea, But unfortunately Return No value, or I'm missing something. I'm using VB 2010 express. Hope you can revise the code accordingly on this vb version. It will be highly appreciated. Looking forward on the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working with window application with vb.net ?

Comment: Hi Chetan, Yes, Thanks for the response !

Comment: Hi chetan hope you recieved previous response. Thanks

Comment: Thanks chetan, This one works, thanks for your assistance.! Appreciated.